# Can't acces my JSON files with ES6

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

I'm working on a little chat application where you can click on different contacts and see / send messages.

I have this users.json file with the contacts:

```
{
   "results":[
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":{
            "title":"Ms",
            "first":"Leonie",
            "last":"Otto"
         },
         "location":{
            "street":"3076 raiffeisenstraße",
            "city":"meißen",
            "state":"sachsen-anhalt",
            "postcode":62480
         },
         "email":"leonie.otto@example.com",
         "login":{
            "username":"bigwolf465",
            "password":"stephane",
            "salt":"Ip5qcgs5",
            "md5":"fe5df54750c64b7c5d54c92f0cb91f11",
            "sha1":"17d255fb64135b5e247a4ef5554557a1d2a8881e",
            "sha256":"341d750fce611b853b4f27d485f10ef9f9c3add4de12a7fbf838a1fd2d5168a9"
         },
         "dob":"1955-01-08 01:03:55",
         "registered":"2012-07-07 16:42:10",
         "phone":"0265-7006038",
         "cell":"0178-0561111",
         "id":{
            "name":"",
            "value":null
         },
         "picture":{
            "large":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/women/8.jpg",
            "medium":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/med/women/8.jpg",
            "thumbnail":"https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/8.jpg"
         },
         "nat":"DE",
         "status": "online"
      },
      {
         "gender":"female",
         "name":{
            "title":"Miss",
            "first":"Olive",
            "last":"Wright"
         },
         "location":{
            "street":"2912 manukau road",
            "city":"timaru",
            "state":"otago",
            "postcode":30721
         },
         "email":"olive.wright@example.com",
         "login":{
            "username":"brownrabbit413",
            "password":"derek",
            "salt":"gRxy7hHq",
            "md5":"dc214ffe467373790c8500abd1ff0f8f",
            "sha1":"7b7847e1a9e3b3de081e3eeebf972dc5d2b5527a",
            "sha256":"1763dff5c43e1cea431d1ad8c1648c586af9d1e1410001d743078af143ce30b9"
         },
         "dob":"1982-07-01 12:12:29",
         "registered":"2016-03-25 19:15:33",
         "phone":"(003)-127-5232",
         "cell":"(133)-307-2001",
         "id":{
            "name":"",
            "value":null
         },
         "picture":{
            "large":"assets/img/users/233899238.jpg"
         },
         "nat":"NZ",
         "status": "online"
      }
```

I both put them in a list item where I show their name, username and profile picture. This all works out well.

The next I want is that if I click on the specific contact, it shows all their message history.

So as an example for the contact with the username bigwolf465 I use this json file:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "messages": [
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "me",
            "text": "Can I have this?",
            "ts": "1512085950.000216"
        },
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "other",
            "text": "No.",
            "ts": "1512085950.218404"
        },
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "me",
            "text": "Ah, perhaps I’ve miscommunicated. I’m asking for it because I want it.",
            "ts": "1512085950.000216"
        },
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "other",
            "text": "I understood that, actually.",
            "ts": "1512085950.000216"
        },
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "me",
            "text": "I think maybe you’re not hearing me. I’d like it because I want it.",
            "ts": "1512085950.000216"
        },
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "other",
            "text": "There's no problem with my hearing. The problem is that your argument is, as the Romans would say:",
            "ts": "1512085950.000216"
        },
        {
            "type": "message",
            "user": "other",
            "text": "Circulus in probando.",
            "ts": "1512085950.000216"
        }
    ],
    "pin_count": 0
}
```

I also want to make a list item for these messages, but it doens't seem to work out. This is the JS code I have right now:

```
const handleContactClick = ({
  currentTarget: $li
}) => {
  loadContactDetails($li);
};

const loadContactDetails = $li => {
  fetch(`./assets/data/messages/${$li.dataset.username}.json`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(parseContactDetail);
}

const parseContactDetail = messages => {
  const $container = document.querySelector(`.messages-list`);

  const $li = document.createElement(`li`);
  $li.classList.add(`reply`);
  $container.appendChild($li);

  const $img = document.createElement(`img`);
  $img.setAttribute(`src`, `assets/img/me.png`);
  $li.appendChild($img);

  const $p = document.createElement(`p`);
  $p.textContent = `${messages.text}`;
  $li.appendChild($p);
}
```

When I click on the specific contact, it just adds messages with the text "undefined". I don't really know how to fix it, it seems I can't get acces to the JSON file.

Comment: Can you please replicate this in codepen and Ill check it out.

Comment: I don't have codepen pro, so I can't add my JSON files

Comment: @AndrewL Please don't ask for a codepen. If an [mcve] is missing, ask for a [stacksnippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Comment: You want to make a list, but there's no loop, nothing. The JSON file you posted is an Object which contains an Object `messages`, which contains an Array of Objects with a `text` key. Your code does not reflect this in any sense.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD What does this question have to do with ES6? Do you have working ES5 code?

Comment: @Bergi I didnt asked him to remove the code snippets provided above nor am I saying this question should be closed because the current question provides the necessary info for future readers to benefit from. What I asked for is more of a personal request 'in the comments' so I could check his code and post the solution here again so future readers can benefit from it. He doesn't have to provide the link if he doesn't want to since it is not mandatory of course. But if I'm asking him to remove his provided code snippets and post a codepen instead on the question, then yeah, I get your point :)

Comment: @AndrewL https://streamable.com/0jk7p does this make my problem clear?

Comment: Chris G posted the correct solution, I'll just add a quick note for future reference: in cases like this, try writing your variables to the console first. For example, if you had written `console.log(messages);` in the first line of `parseContactDetail()`, you probably would have seen the problem yourself.

Comment: @MátéSafranka I do that too lol Really nifty trick for debugging my codes.

Comment: @MátéSafranka Thanks! I will try to do that in the future. I'm in my first year of learning programming, so a lot of things are new for me, but yeah you are right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function, fixed:

```
const parseContactDetail = person => {
  const $container = document.querySelector(`.messages-list`);

  person.messages.forEach(m => {
    const $li = document.createElement(`li`);
    $li.classList.add(`reply`);
    $container.appendChild($li);

    const $img = document.createElement(`img`);
    $img.setAttribute(`src`, `assets/img/me.png`);
    $li.appendChild($img);

    const $p = document.createElement(`p`);
    $p.textContent = `${m.text}`;
    $li.appendChild($p);

  });
}
```

The function now properly grabs `.messages` from the passed data object, then loops over the array, creating a `<li>` for each element.

Comment: Given the video you posted, you should probably clear the container first.

Comment: *What* did you fix in the function?